# in traditional can (not FD) what do the __res0 and __res1 bytes represent?

Tags: can-bus

I've been using `tcpdump` to capture exactly what my system is sending to can:

```
4a02 0000 0800 0000 2011 0123 4567 890A
4a02 0000 0800 0000 2111 0123 4567 890A
```

And for the most part, the bytes after the length (8) are always 00 0000 and then the real data of my payload starts.

But every so often:

```
4a02 0000 08e4 0bcc 2011 0123 4567 890A
4a02 0000 08a7 5ea7 2111 0123 4567 890A
```

The pad, res0, and res1 bytes are filled in:

```
struct can_frame {
    canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
    __u8    can_dlc; /* frame payload length in byte (0 .. CAN_MAX_DLEN) */
    __u8    __pad;   /* padding */
    __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    data[CAN_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

What causes __pad, __res0 and _res1 to be filled in and how should I interpret their meaning?

Comment: You should not interpret those fields, they surely have some internal use (I'm having a look at it) but it doesn't mean that it has any relevance for you (hence the "reserved").

Comment: well I'm trying to write my own software on windows that will send the exact same bits down the wire as linux does. I feel like I need to set these reserved ones too or the bits will not be 100% identical from linux to windows.

Comment: Those bits won't be transmitted on the CAN wires. If your goal is to write a windows software that sends CAN messages, you should only care about the CAN specification and not how it is implemented on Linux.

Comment: so tcpdump is showing me bits that are NOT transferred?

Comment: If you are using a CAN line, your frame will be as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). If you are using CAN over something, I don't know